# Windows EC2 to have FHD (1920x1080) Resolution

Tags: amazon-ec2, automation, selenium-chromedriver, screen-resolution, amazon-ami

In my use case, I have Selenium automation test running on AWS windows EC2 Agent. As per the requirement,  the resolution should be FHD(1920x1080) in windows Agents where Selenium test will run.

Again, **AWS Windows EC2 by default supports only 1024x768 resolution**. `Set-DisplayResolution -Width 1920 -Height 1080 -Force` command also did not work. But if I am RDP in to that EC2 from my laptop which has FHD(1920x1080) resolution, then the resolution of the machine getting set to FHD(1920x1080).

I have to create 70 such Agent (on AWS Windows EC2) for Selenium test to run. And its painful to RDP to each Agent to set the resolution. Is there any way we can set the resolution with out **manually** RDP in to Windows Agents (AWS EC2)? I mean any automated way to achieve this ?

Comment: Probably just backup the registry before after and compare. why not just create an Ami off your current machine?

Comment: Your talking about the RDP setting it so mstsc /f will do that